# Suppress scientific notation with locale.format()

Tags: python, floating-point, formatting, locale, number-formatting

I use `locale.format()` to separate numbers into commas, but that function doesn't get rid of scientific notation. I want a way to return a number separated into commas, with trailed zeros and no scientific notation.

Example of actual code: `1160250.1294254328` -> `1.16025e+06`

Example of I want: `1160250.1294254328` -> `1,160,250.13`

My code:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')

x = 1160250.1294254328
x = round(x, 2)
x = locale.format("%g", x, grouping=True, monetary=True)
```

Comment: `'{:,.2f}'.format(1160250.1294254328)` --> `'1,160,250.13'` [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the first time that locale package to me.

Taking this opportunity to study the locale package, I found out that this package is very related to string formatting operations.

%g is only for exponential floating-point formatting.

Therefore, for the format you want, it is better to use the format below.

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_us.utf-8')
x = 1160250.1294254328
x = locale.format("%.2f", x, grouping=True, monetary=True)

print(x)
```

If you are interested in the String formatting operator check out the link below.

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

Try use f-strings:

```
x = 1160250.1294254328
x = round(x, 2)
print(f"{x:,}") # -> Output: 1,160,250.13
```